# Spring @RequestMapping not parsing an int ID

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm trying to return a user object in a restful service using Spring 4, with Spring Boot (Tomcat without MVC), but it's not parsing the entirely object to JSON. My User.java:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String username;
private String password;

// getters and setters
}
```

My service:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/service/user/save", method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces="application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1", consumes="application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1")
public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws AppException
{
    return facade.save(user); // returns a User with it's ID
}
```

And my JSON result (without ID):

```
{
username: "john",
password: "1234",
}
```

The parsing is happening only for username and password.
However, when I return a String manually parsed, like in:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/service/user/save", method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces="application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1", consumes="application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1")
public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws AppException
{
    user = facade.save(user);
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user);
}
```

It works fine, returning:

```
{
id: 23,
username: "john",
password: "1234",
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: What is the difference between facade and cs? `return facade.save(user);` `user = cs.save(user);` are they different classes?

Comment: No differences - it's the same object (I've fixed that on this post).